# QTableWidget has item assigned twice, why?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I've created a widget with a Table in it, and when I convert it using `pyuic`, I get the below code, nothing too weird so far. It's when we get to the second `item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()` that I don't understand what is happening. It looks like to me that it's reassigning the variable `item` again. But if I delete the second assignment table outputs `Short | Short`. This doesn't make sense why that should be the case. Why should deleting the second assigned `item` make the top of my table different?

```
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(("Form"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(("Descrip"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(("Short"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is only logical.

```
item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
# item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
```

If you delete the third line the `item` variable will keep on referencing to the same instance. So in the last line you will basically reference the same data as in the first header item. So you end up with two header items that use the same QTableWidgetItem for data.

Now let' s have a look at `retranslateUi()`:

```
item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
item.setText(("Descrip"))
item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
item.setText(("Short"))
```

First and second line you will retrieve the item instance and add the text 'Descrip' to it. Then you will get the item of the second header item which is exactly the same object as before. So in the last line you will set the text to 'Short' and both your headers will show 'Short'.

If you want to check use the following code:

```
item1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
item2 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
print(item1 == item2)
```